# Adjacent sibling selector is not working for h3 element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

My HTML DOM is given below. I want to remove margin and padding for all h3 elements which is an immediate sibling of div (id=successor). I used adjacent sibling selector "+" to acheive this.
But im not getting the expected output. Please help me.

```
<style type="text/css">
    div#successor {
       display: block;
   }
   div#successor+h3 {
      padding :0 !important;
      margin :0 !important;
      border: 1px solid red;
   }
</style>
<div id="access">
<div class="profile clearfix">
    <div id="successor" class="memeberDetails">
        <h3>Personal</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam purus dolor, vulputate iaculis erat ut, pulvinar commodo orci.Cras ac lorem a lectus luctus vestibulum. Suspendisse odio ligula, fringilla ut ultrices sed, aliquam nec ligula. Praesent porttitor,</p>
        <br />
        <h3>Training</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam purus dolor, vulputate iaculis erat ut, pulvinar commodo orci.</p>
        <br />
        <h3>Contact</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I'm reading that right, `div#successor` is the *parent* of all the `h3`s, not their sibling.

Comment: that's what I was thinking, so you need to select the immediate child

Comment: U is you and R is are. Not being a perfectionist but lets do what is right :)

Comment: @Drixson Oseña  I changed my comment. thanks english giant..!!

Comment: @vandu no I'm not good at english also and I'm asian :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add styles to `h3` elements you need to select them by:

```
div#successor>h3
```

Adjacent selector selects element next to the object on the left of '+' operator, so it will work if you have such structure:

```
<div id="successor" class="memeberDetails">
    ...
</div>
<h3>...</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

As *IMSoP* said `#successor` is the parent and you want to select its immediate child.
You might want to use : `div#successor>h3`
Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Au4Vh/